# How to config restful api has many version in cakephp 3.0

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0, restful-url

I want to create api with link same  api/v1/controller/action. But i can not config router. Please help me!
Thanks you!

Answer (score 4):

You use router scopes for that:

```
Router::scope('/api/v1', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/posts', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index']);
    ... // More routes here
});

Router::scope('/api/v2', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/posts', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index_v2']);
    ... // More routes here
});
```

Comment: I create to succeed
Thanks you very much!